# Haxe error with generic function

Tags: generics, haxe

I'm trying to create a function with generic parameters, but I having errors when I instantiate the function.

```
class Util {
    @:generic
    public static inline function max<T>( a:T, b:T ) : T {
        return a > b ? a : b;
    }
}
```

Calling `max` without setting the type:

```
var mean:Float = 0;
mean = Util.max( 0.01, mean );
```

I'm getting the errors:

```
Cannot compare max.T and max.T
Missing return max.T
```

If I set Float type instead:

```
var mean:Float = 0;
mean = Util.max<Float>( 0.01, mean );
```

I get the errors:

```
Unexpected ,
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `T` might not have a `>` operator. Perhaps you can use a type constraint like:

```
class Util {
    @:generic
    public static inline function max<T:Float>(a:T, b:T):T {
        return a > b ? a : b;
    }
}
```

And then usage like this should work:

```
var intMax:Int = Util.max(1, 10);
var floatMax:Float = Util.max(1.0, 10.0);
```

Comment: thanks, probably I was expecting a C++ template that checks for the `> operator` existence when you use/instantiate the template.